# How to add content of one file in another file at specific line using batch script?

Tags: batch-file

Lets say I have two files (file1.txt & file2.txt).

Content of file1.txt is

```
line number 4
line number 5
line number 6
```

Content of file2.txt is

```
line number 1
line number 2
line number 3
line number 7
line number 8
```

How to add content of file1.txt in file2.txt after line number 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
copy file1.txt+file2.txt file3.txt
sort file3.txt >file4.txt
```

output in file4.txt

--- revised goal

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q40715794.txt"
SET "filename2=%sourcedir%\q40715794_2.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
SET "insertafter=line number 3"
(
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename2%") DO (
 ECHO %%a
 IF "%%a"=="%insertafter%" TYPE "%filename1%"
)
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a files named `q40715794.txt` and `q40715794_2.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as %outfile%

read and `echo` the second file until the contents of the line matches the insert point, then `type` the first file, then read and `echo` the remainder of the second file.

Comment: Magoo,
I have two source code files. I can merge it, but what i want it to place content of first file at a specific line number of second file.

Comment: Your question clearly states "Or how to merge both files such that all lines are ordered as per line number?" This will accomplish that end. Please clarify

Answer (score 3):

[Magoo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40715834/7170434) pretty much already gave you an answer but if you really want to give a linenumber instead of the content of the line you can maybe use this:

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set file1=%~1
set file2=%~2
set lineswitch=%~3

IF [%file1%] == [] goto :wrongUsage
IF [%file2%] == [] goto :wrongUsage
IF [%lineswitch%] == [] goto :wrongUsage

IF [%~4] == [] (
    set out=%file1%
) ELSE (
    set out=%~4
)

REM Create temporary file to copy content of file1
set tmpfile=%temp%\lineshrink_cpy.tmp
copy %file1% %tmpfile% > nul

REM clear output-file
type nul > "%out%"

set /a line=0
FOR /F "tokens=* usebackq" %%G IN ("%tmpfile%") DO (
    set /a line+=1
    IF !line! EQU %lineswitch% (
        type "%file2%" >> "%out%"
    )
    echo %%G >> "%out%"
)

REM Delete tempfile
del %tmpfile%
EndLocal
exit /b 0

:wrongUsage
echo SYNTAX: APPENDER.BAT file1 file2 lineswitch [output]
EndLocal
exit /b 1
```

This batch-script will take at least 3 arguments: `file1`, `file2` and `lineswitch`. It will insert `file2` into `file1` beginning at line number `lineswhitch` (1-based counting). So the first line of `file2` will become line number `lineswitch` in `file1` (2nd line will be line number `lineswitch + 1` and so on, ...). If you don't want `file1` to change but you want the result in another file, just give that file as fourth argument. The fourth argument is additional though, but be carefull and surround paths containing spaces with double quotes!

If you put that script in a file appender.bat and you use it with your files (file1.txt and file2.txt) like this:

```
>appender.bat file2.txt file1.txt 4 file3.txt
```

You'll end up with file1.txt and file2.txt unchanged and a file3.txt with following content:

```
line number 1
line number 2
line number 3
line number 4
line number 5
line number 6
line number 7
line number 8
```

On the other hand if you use it like this:

```
>appender.bat file2.txt file1.txt 4
```

You'll end up with file1.txt unchanged but file2.txt will be:

```
line number 1
line number 2
line number 3
line number 4
line number 5
line number 6
line number 7
line number 8
```

If you give an unvalid 3rd argument (non positive integer or not an integer at all) the result will be the same as the original first file: all files will remain unchanged except the 4th argument(if you gave one), it will then be a copy of the first file.

Maybe some useful links that can help you understand the working:

- [this one](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_math.php) explains how you can use the `set` command and its `/a` switch for arithmetic operations
- [this one](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) is about delayed expansion. I use it here because a FOR-loop is treated as one command (as if written on one line) and you can't change/set the value of a variable and read the new value from the same line. That's why I use `SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion` and `!line!` instead of `%line%` inside the loop.
- if you want more info about [the `FOR /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) or about [all loops that exist in batch](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html)

Good luck!